# Where does React maintain supported/recommended Node versioning info?

Tags: node.js, reactjs

Mac here, new to Node and React. I installed `nvm` via `brew install nvm` because I like the idea of a tool like NVM making it easy to install and switch around to different Node.js versions for different projects.

I am looking to create a React 18 project, but for the life of me I can't find any authoritative sources on what Node/NPM versions are supported/recommended for React 18. Could someone not only tell me what these versions are, but show me where (ideally within the React.js org) this information is given, so as to *educate* me for projects in the future? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Crickets?! Fascinating! That would be like Java developers not knowing what version of Java a particular version of Spring requires! Does React _not_ require Node to run?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Surprisingly the only way to find which version of Node is supported by React is to look at the source code:

1. Go to React’s project on GH → https://github.com/facebook/react
2. Click on the **Releases** link
3. Scroll down and select the React version you are targeting
4. Click its commit link
5. In the top-right corner click on **Browse Files**
6. Go to `package.json` file and look to see what its `devEngines` entries are for `node`

Crazy! As a Java developer I give 2 thumbs down!